# How do I install program only for a local user in Linux?

Tags: linux, installation

Is there a simple way of installing a program in linux only for a single user.  I need to install Biopython for only my log-in.  I dont have root privileges on the system.

Comment: Are you building it from source or trying to use a package manager?

Comment: I dont have access to the package manager, I have to go the build-compile way.

Comment: For installing python packages that have a `setup.py` in their source, the procedure is as follows `python setup.py build; python setup.py install --prefix=${HOME}/local`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just build the project as usual, but configure the install directory to be either /home/usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 1):

You can always download and compile the program in your home directory (in ~/apps), and then just invoke the executable (possibly add ~/apps/specificapp/bin/specificapp to your PATH).  Don't forget to chmod it so it is executable.

Answer (score 0):

Although an old question, here's how to install into local user bin directory, without using sudo:

```
install ./your-app ~/.local/bin/
```